# Assign `call system()` result to a Fortran variable

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I am using this piece of code to review the number of files of  a folder

```
call system ('dir c:\data /B /A-d|find /v /c "*"')
```

I need to assign it to a variable. I have tried everything.

Comment: *I have tried everything* - If you indeed had tried *everything* without success, then the task obviously cannot be implemented. So most likely you have not tried everything. Thus, please explain what you have tried and in what why that failed.

Comment: To a large degree, this is the same as [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7839100/3157075).

Comment: @EduJCeb, I have deleted your Thanks on purpose. If you really want it there, keep it, but we normally try to remove all noise and have the questions and answers clean and concise. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: Can not be done. Need a file.