# Save command line output to variable in Fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

Is there a way to store the output of a command line utility to a variable in Fortran?

I have a BASH based utility which gives me a number which needs to be used in a Fortran program. I want to call the utility through the program itself, and avoid writing the output to a file if possible.

Something like this maybe?

```
integer a
write(a,*) call execute_command_line('echo 5')
```

Or like this maybe?

```
read(call execute_command_line('echo 5'),*) a
```

I don't think either of these is right though. I would like to know if there is actually a method to do this. I read the docs for `execute_command_line` but I don't think there is an output argument for the subroutine which does this.

Comment: You'll have to use a temporary "file".  I can't immediately find a question which I thought covered this, but some discussion is in [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7839100/3157076).

Comment: I have been trying and failing to make the fortranposix library mentioned in the question (an fPIC error for an object file which is not there in the Makefile). While I am figuring it out, is there any other library which adds posix functionalities like popen to Fortran? Or any other way which does not depend on external, non default libraries? @francescalus

Comment: Some compilers bundle POSIX-like things in their runtime, so you may have luck there.  But, to be honest, I'd just write standard output of the command to a real file and read it from my Fortran program.

Comment: Thing is, this will go into a program for differential evolution with millions of generations, with 40 models, each with 4 model parameters, looped over 120 data points, so total iterations would be 19200000000 at max. I don't know if writing to a file and then reading from it each time would be the best thing to do here. The whole point of writing a differential evolution algorithm is to make things faster. I would have preferred to not have to read and write a file in each iteration

Comment: You also have the full range of options of inter-process communication.  [Again, I expect there are questions around here, but I can't seem to find a good one for you.]

Comment: Please do mention any questions you do happen to find. Thank you for your help.

Comment: This article about named pipes is interesting  https://www.networkworld.com/article/3251853/linux/why-use-named-pipes-on-linux.html (which says that everything is performed on memory. But I wonder whether a huge number of system calls background is no problem or have some practical issue...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're using BASH, lets assume you're working on some kind of unix-like system. So you could use a FIFO. Something like

```
program readfifo
  implicit none
  integer :: u, i
  logical :: ex
  inquire(exist=ex, file='foo')
  if (.not. ex) then
     call execute_command_line ("mkfifo foo")
  end if
  call execute_command_line ("echo 5 > foo&")
  open(newunit=u, file='foo', action='read')
  read(u, *) i
  write(*, *) 'Managed to read the value ', i
end program readfifo
```

Note that the semantics of FIFO's wrt blocking can be a bit tricky (that's why there is the '&' after the echo command, you might want to read up on it a bit and experiment (particularly make sure you haven't got a zillion bash processes hanging around when you do this multiple times).

Comment: So, is using named pipes faster than using normal files? Like in the above code, if I don't use the command `mkfifo foo`, and just write it to a normal file, and then read from it, would it be comparably slower? Because as far as I understood, even making a named pipe will have to write a file to the disk

Comment: @Yuki.kuroshita: Well, you have to create the FIFO entry in the directory yes, but then all I/O to/from that FIFO never hits the filesystem. So if you create the FIFO only once, and then keep it open in Fortran, I guess it would be pretty efficient. Well, roughly as efficient as a pipe, since that's what it is.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation

Comment: What is the function of the & at the end of the system command? I would think that, in order to get the desired behavior, you would have to do `call execute_command_line("echo 5 > foo",WAIT=.t.)`