# Is there a gfortran way to automatically read in all the files that are named in a particular way in a given directory?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

My gfortran program needs to be able to read in data from an unknown number of files in a given directory.  The program needs to step through the files in the directory, determine if the name of the file has a certain form and if so, read in the name and then pass the file name to a subroutine that reads in the data from that file.

I see that one can use `execute_command_line(COMMAND)`, perhaps in conjunction with `ls file*` to read in all the files with name `file###`, but this is printed to the terminal.  It would be useful if I could read the result into a dummy list file which I can then iterate over.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour], read [ask] and use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions.You can save the result of the ls command into a file and read that fille in Fortran }we have duplicates about this). If your files are named in a predictable way, you can just loop over them very simply. Please specify if you can predict the names of those files and how exactly are they named.

Comment: How to get the output of an external process: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53447665/save-command-line-output-to-variable-in-fortran?noredirect=1&lq=1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839100/execute-command-line-and-return-command-output

Comment: Thanks Vladimir for your pointer to the duplicates, they helped and I was able to solve the problem completely.  The names of the files are not a priori predictable, but their form is, so I read in all the files of a certain form into a new file and then looped through this new list.  Works like a charm!